# Remove duplicates Objects from List in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I know this kind of question is asked in stackoverflow lots of time before. But my issue is little bit different and I could not find any similar scenario, so posting this question here

Problem:
I need to remove duplicate objects from ArrayList. Structure of my arrayList is as below

```
dataList.add(new ObjectClass("a","b"));
dataList.add(new ObjectClass("c","n"));
dataList.add(new ObjectClass("b","a")); // should be counted as duplicate
dataList.add(new ObjectClass("z","x"));
```

I need to remove objects from above list such as, it treats combination of "a,b" and "b,a" as duplicates and remove any of those duplicate

My solution:
step 1) Override equals method in DataClass class

```
class DataClass {
      String source;
      String destination;
    
      DataClass(String src, String dest) {
        this.source = src;
        this.destination = dest;
      }
    
      // getter setter for source and destination variables

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside equals");
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ObjectClass other = (ObjectClass) obj;
        if(i.equals(other.getJ())
            && j.equals(other.getI())) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
```

step 2) method to remove duplicates

```
public List<DataClass> removeDuplicates(List<DataClass> dataList) {
            List<DataClass> resultList = new ArrayList<DataClass>();
        
            // Convert array list to Linked list
            LinkedList<DataClass> linkedList = new LinkedList<DataClass>();
            for(DataClass obj: dataList) {
                linkedList.add(obj);
            }
            
            // Iterate through linked list and remove if values are duplicates
            for(int i = 0; i<linkedList.size();i++) {
              for(int j = i+1;j<linkedList.size();j++) {
                if(linkedList.get(j).equals(linkedList.get(i))) {
                    linkedList.remove();
                }
              }
            }
            resultList.addAll(linkedList);
            return resultList;
        }
```

I am still looking for any better optimized solution, if there is any. Thanks in advance

**Update with solution**
: my equals method was needed to correct some comparison logic. So here is my updated ObjectClass instead of DataClass including correct overridden equals method

```
public class ObjectClass {
    String i;
    String j;
    public  ObjectClass(String i, String j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
    // getters setters
    // override hashcode
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ObjectClass other = (ObjectClass) obj;

        if((i.equals(other.getJ()) || i.equals(other.getI()))
            && (j.equals(other.getI()) || j.equals(other.getJ()))) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }   
}
```

2. After fixing equals method I tried below implementation in removeDuplicate method as Janos mentioned and it is working fine as expected

   ```
    for(ObjectClass obj: dataList) {
        if(!resultList.contains(obj))
            resultList.add(obj);
    }
   ```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for... a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?

Comment: Do you mean `new DataClass("a","b")` and `new DataClass("z","x")` are duplicates (equals) ?  
And why there is `ObjectClass` in the equals method of `DataClass`?

Comment: The issues in this Question have indeed been handled many many times already on Stack Overflow. Please search thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @vinS: No, i mean (a,b) and (b,a) are duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

> ```
> class DataClass {
>       String source;
>       String destination;
>
>       // ...
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>         // ...
>         ObjectClass other = (ObjectClass) obj;
>         if(i.equals(other.getJ())
>             && j.equals(other.getI())) {
>             return true;
>         } else return false;
>     }
> ```

The `equals` method casts the other object to `ObjectClass`.
It should cast to the same class where this method is defined: `DataClass`.

The `equals` method compares `i` and `j` variables,
but they are not defined anywhere within the class.
There's `source` and `destination`.

The `equals` method will return true when `this.i` is the same as `other.j` and `this.j` is the same as `other.i`, and return false otherwise. In other words, `(a, b)` will be equal to `(b, a)`. But it will not be equal to itself. That's very strange, and probably not what you intended.

---

The `removeDuplicates` method is overcomplicated.
For example converting an array list to a linked list is unnecessary.
Here's a much simpler algorithm:

- For each value in the source list

  - If the value does not exist in the result list, add it to the result list

That's it.

```
List<DataClass> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (DataClass item : dataList) {
    if (!result.contains(item)) {
        result.add(item);
    }
}
return result;
```

This assumes that the implementation of the `equals` method is fixed.
Otherwise the `result.contains` step will not work correctly.

Also note that `result.contains` performs a linear search:
it checks every item until it finds a match.
You could improve performance by using a set.

Comment: Just a simple suggestion for improving performance. If the constraint is such that its always a single character in "source" and "destination" then we could have a temporary array of size: 'z' + 'z' = 244 + 1 = 245. Notice that any combination of two character is same, e.g: 'a' + 'b' = 195 = 'b' + 'a', so first time we see a combination 'a' + 'b' we set that index-195 to '1' and second time when we see that 'b' + 'a' and see that index-195 is already 1, then we can safely say that its a repetition. O(n) complexity for finding is now O(1).

Comment: @ShababbKarim: Initially I though the same solution. But as of now I am not sure if my object values would be character only all the time. So just to implement more generic logic, I was trying different options. Thanks for your time though

Comment: @janos: sorry for code mess of DataClass/ObjectClass. I updated the answer above. fixing equals method and iteration over arraylist worked very fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

With your code

```
    linkedList.remove();
```

Each time it removes an item from `linkedList`, the indexes of all following items are decremented.  That is going to mess up your iteration loop.

Comment: True. Removed linkedList logic :)

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
DataClass dc = new DataClass("a","b");
List<DataClass> resultList = new ArrayList<DataClass>();
resultList .add(dc);

for (int i=0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
 if(resultList.get(i).source.equals(dc.source) && resultList.get(i).destination.equals(dc.destination) || resultList.get(i).source.equals(dc.destination) && resultList.get(i).destination.equals(dc.source)) {
    resultList.remove(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: Useful commands are appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashSet` for `equals` and `hashCode` so that it does not distinguish order.:

```
class DataClass {
  String source;
  String destination;
  private final Set<String> content = new HashSet< String >();

  DataClass(String src, String dest) {
    this.source = src;
    this.destination = dest;
    content.add(src);
    content.add(dest);
  }

  // getter setter for source and destination variables

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("inside equals");
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!DataClass.class.equals(obj.getClass()))
        return false;
    DataClass other = (DataClass) obj;
    return content.equals(other.content);
}

public int hashCode() {
    return content.hashCode();
}
```

For further reading to how to implement `equals` and `hashCode`, you might want to read https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

---

Use `LinkedHashSet` for finding duplicates:

```
public List<DataClass> removeDuplicates(List<DataClass> dataList) {
    return new ArrayList<DataClass>(new LinkedHashSet<DataClass>(dataList));
}
```

Why we use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`? `LinkedHashSet` preserves ordering while `HashSet` does not. Quoted from `LinkedHashSet` javadoc:

> This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which
>   elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).

Comment: Yes. LinkedHashSet is good solution too. But I went with existing ArrayList 
 logic since it requires minimum changes in ObjectClass. Thank you for your feedback